# Why we can not apply counting sort to general arrays?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, counting-sort

Counting sort is known with linear time **if** we know that all elements in the array are upper bounded by a given number. If we take a general array, cant we just scan the array in linear time, to find the maximum value in the array and then to apply counting sort?

Answer (score 8):

It is not enough to know the upper bound to run a counting sort: you need to have enough memory to fit all the counters.

Consider a situation when you go through an array of 64-bit integers, and find out that the largest element is 2^60. This would mean two things:

- You need an O(2^60) memory, and
- It is going to take O(2^60) to complete the sort.

The fact that `O(2^60)` is the same as `O(1)` is of little help here, because the constant factor is simply too large. This is very often a problem with pseudo-polynomial time algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the largest number is like 235684121.
Then you'll spend incredible amounts of RAM to keep your buckets.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention something with @dasblinkenlight and @AlbinSunnanbo answers, your idea to scan the array in `O(n)` pass, to find the maximum value in the array is okay. Below is given from Wikipedia:

> However, if the value of k is not already known then it may be
>   computed by an additional loop over the data to determine the maximum
>   key value that actually occurs within the data.

As the time complexity is `O(n + k)` and `k` should be under a certain limit, your found `k` should be small. As @dasblinkenlight mentioned, `O(large_value)` can't practically be converged to `O(1)`.

Though I don't know about any major applications of Counting sort so far except used as a **subroutine of Radix Sort**, it can be nicely used in problems like *string sorting*( i.e. sort "android" to "addnoir") as here `k` is only 255.