# Why is counting sort not used for large inputs?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, counting-sort

Counting sort is the sorting algorithm with a average time complexity of O(n+K), and the counting sort assumes that each of the input element is an integer in the range of 0 to K.

Why can't we linear-search the maximum value in an unsorted array, equal it to K, and hence apply counting sort on it?

Comment: Most of the time you don't only sort integers. You sort integers along with their accompanying data. Simple counting sort cant do that.

Comment: The space complexity is one issue. But, in general, you can. It'll just be [slow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25001922/645270) for moderately large ranges.

Comment: What do actually mean about "memory write is free"? Remember the compare complex objects and structures is also part of the computational cost.

Comment: Actually, counting sort does use much more memory than other comparison-based sorts. Hence, just wanted to compare the algorithmic aspect of counting sort.

Comment: That statement doesn't really make sense, seeing as *both* time and space complexity of counting sort are the same: Ω(n + K)

Comment: Sorry. Have edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where your inputs are arrays with `maximum - minimum = O(n log n)` (i.e. the  range of values is reasonably restricted), this actually makes sense. If this is not the case, a standard comparison-based sort algorithm or even an integer sorting algorithm like radix sort is asymptotically better.

To give you an example, the following algorithm generates a family of inputs on which counting sort has runtime complexity `Θ(n^2)`:

```
def generate_input(n):
    array = []
    for i := 1 to n:
        array.append(i*i);
    shuffle(array)
    return array
```

Comment: Can you please explain what K = O(n log n) means? I mean, K is a constant here. How can a constant have a time complexity?

Comment: No, K is not a constant. K is a function of the input. Keep in mind that Landau O-notation can be used for arbitrary mathematical functions, not just functions representing instruction counts/run times

Comment: @Joao: Let `f(n)` be the runtime of counting sort on the given family of inputs. We have `f(n) = Θ(n + k) = Θ(n^2)`, hence my claim is correct.

Comment: According to Thomas Cormen Introduction to Algorithms book, counting sort is `Ω(n + k)` and `O(n + k)`, if `k` is `O(n)`. Thus using numbers much bigger than the length of the array, as mentioned by Niklas, violates a precondition that makes `Θ(n + k)`. So if there is a `k = Θ(nˆ2)` in the array, then the time complexity becomes `Θ(n^2)`

Answer (score 3):

Your heading of the question is **Why is counting sort not used for large inputs?**

What we do in counting sort? We take another array (suppose b[]) and initialize all element to zero. Then we increment an index if that index is an element of the given array. Then we run a loop from lower limit to upper limit of the given array and check if element of index of my taken array (b[]) is 0 or not. If it is not zero, that means, that index is an element of given array.

Now, If the difference between this two (upper limit & lower limit) is very high(like 10^9 or more), then a single loop is enough to kill our PC. :)

Comment: I was hoping that question would come up. I thought if we could use `std::map` to index the element of that array. The only problem was, to keep track of the elements present, so there would be another `std::set`. This is a naive approach, if you can tell me something better.

Comment: @ShauryaChats Insertion into `std::set` and `std::map` is O(log n) though, so that ruins the advantage that counting sort has in the first place. You can't use hash tables instead, because you will have to iterate over the existing elements in sorted order. But if you can do the latter, you don't need to sort anymore

Answer (score 0):

According to [Big-O notation definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), if we say `f(n) ∈ O(g(n))`, it means that there is a value `C > 0` and `n = N` such that `f(n) < C*g(n)`, where `C` and `N` are constants. Nothing is said about the value of `C` nor for which `n = N` the inequality is true.

In any the algorithm analysis, the cost of each operation of the Turing machine must be considered (compare, move, sum, etc). The value of such costs are the defining factors of how big (or small) the values of `C` and `N` must be in order to turn the inequality true or false. Remove these cost is a naive assumption I myself used to do during the algorithm analysis course.

The statement "counting sort is `O(n+k)`" actually means that the sorting is polynomial and linear for a given `C`, `n > N`,`n > K`, where `C`, `N`, and `K` are constants. Thus other algorithms may have a better performance for smaller inputs, because the inequality is true only if the given conditions are true.